# Is this what my page should look like?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, external, stylesheet

So I'm basically wondering if the code I wrote is supposed to just pop up a page with "This web page uses an external style sheet", in blue font. I've been trying for hours to get my CSS to link to my HTML code and finally I did but all it was, was blue font. P.S I'm supposed to turn this in tonight so need to be sure!

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPHUO.png)

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>External Styles</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="color.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <p>This web page uses an external style sheet.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**css:**

```
    body { backround-color: #0000FF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: If you want blue colored text then your `background-color` and `color` values must be reversed. See https://jsfiddle.net/o4436sop/

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. It suppose to show with White Color font with a light background. 
This is some other css or browser plugin's impact.

You can try on the fiddle first to verify what it can look like at a clean state.

https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have wrongly typed `background-color`.
The code you provided is giving you the Blue background with white text.

[image: Sample Output]

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fiddle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="txtPopup">
<p>This web page uses an external style sheet</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
 body { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0000FF
    }
```